# PHP command line: max_execution_time and memory_limit

Tags: php

Quick question.

If I run a php script from the command-line (through a cron job, "php ./somwthing-sync.php"), am I still bounded to the php max_execution_time and memory_limit?

Thanks

Nathan

Comment: Look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874950/set-max-execution-time-in-php-cli

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you look at the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) , its says

```
      max_execution_time  integer

This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is 
terminated by the parser. This helps prevent poorly written scripts from 
tying up the server. The default setting is 30. 
When running PHP from the command line the default setting is 0.
```

A 0 means unlimited. (If i am not wrong). As for memory_limit, the PHP command line will take the value that is defined  in php.ini. This you can easily test and find out by writing code that "eats" memory and setting memory_limit to -1 in php.ini

Comment: No, you are not wrong, time limit is theoretically infinite from command line. In fact, PHP documentation states it explicitly: http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php

Comment: Yes. CLI SAPI default value for "max_execution_time" is set to unlimited.
http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you still are, as the page is still executed and takes up memory.

According to ghostdog, the time limit is removed, but my guess is the memory limit is till in place.

Comment: According to my observations, there's no memory limit as well when running PHP from the command line.