# php7 timeout not enforced

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I've been searching for why for the past 2 days and I tried a lot of solutions on the internet and here on stack.

I have a dedicated VM with ubuntu 16.04 with apache2 -> Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) with the default php instalation: 
php -v

```
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (cli) ( NTS ).
```

phpinfo()

```
PHP Version 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
```

Recently I noticed that the scripts can run for forever, there is no timeout limit enforced.

I did a phpinfo() to get the php.ini file used. I checked inside the php.ini the following parameters:

```
default_socket_timeout = 60
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
```

I even set them to 3 seconds (max_execution_time, max_input_time and default_socket_timeout), restarted apache, but with no results.

The following code for example (and it's not the only one i tried) doesn't time out, it runs until it finishes:

```
echo "<br>initial max_execution_time: " . ini_get('max_execution_time') ;
print_r(set_time_limit(2));
echo " - set_time_limit\n";
echo "<br>initial max_execution_time: " . ini_get('max_execution_time') ;
ini_set('max_execution_time', '1');
echo "<br>initial max_execution_time: " . ini_get('max_execution_time') ;
ini_set('default_socket_timeout','1');
echo "<br>ini_get('default_socket_timeout')". ini_get('default_socket_timeout');
//phpinfo();


set_time_limit(1);
$i = 0;
while(++$i < 1000000001){
        if($i % 100000 == 0){
                echo $i / 100000, "<br/>\n";
        }
}
echo "done.<br/>\n";
```

The output is telling me that the timeouts are correctly set, but like I said, the script is running for 32seconds without being killed.

Any ideas why the timeouts are not applied?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874950/set-max-execution-time-in-php-cli says that even on CLI timeouts should work. I wasn't aware that there are 2 types of php installations (with and without CLI)

Comment: but wait, CLI means command line interface, right? My scripts are executed in a browser like chrome or ffox. This should get the timeouts from php.ini, or?

Comment: i checked all php.ini files, all have at most 30 seconds. But the phpinfo() should show the one that is being used and i checked that one. (i did a find on the server for any php.ini files that might be anywhere)

Comment: Thats true, so I am lost then

Comment: no worries, thanks for your time. it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

max_execution_time does not necessarily translate to how long the http request will take. There are other processes that can be run by your php script that will not get counted as execution time. For example, if you run a large database query, the time it takes will not count toward the max_execution_time. In these cases, it is the apache timeout that will be enforced. On ubuntu, your apache2.conf file should contain a line with:

```
Timeout 300
```

This will be the actual limit that includes the time it takes for all database queries, curl requests, exec calls and other external processes.