# typo3 import news with news_ttnewsimport fails

Tags: typo3, tx-news, tt-news

when importing news form tt_news to news

TYPO3 8.7.1
news 6.0.0
news_ttnewsimport 2.0.0

with
 /usr/local/bin/php7.1.6 ./typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase newsimport:run

the import of news recors stopps after 30 records.

anybody a solution for that?

Comment: Did you try checked `max_execution_time` in php,ini or php-cli.ini. Mb this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874950/set-max-execution-time-in-php-cli

Comment: Thanks. the reason why the import stopped after 30 records was:
the images in the uploads folder were missing.